# ftp .net getdirectory size

Tags: visual-c++, ftp, c++-cli

hi i write method which must to know that is size of specified directory i get response from server which contains flags of file name size and other info and on the different ftp servers format of answer is different how to know format of answer?

```
unsigned long long  GetFtpDirSize(String^ ftpDir) {
unsigned long long  size = 0;
int j = 0;
StringBuilder^ result = gcnew StringBuilder();
StreamReader^ reader;
FtpWebRequest^ reqFTP;
reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest^)FtpWebRequest::Create(gcnew Uri(ftpDir));
reqFTP->UseBinary = true;
reqFTP->Credentials = gcnew NetworkCredential("anonymous", "123");
reqFTP->Method = WebRequestMethods::Ftp::ListDirectoryDetails;
reqFTP->KeepAlive = false;
reqFTP->UsePassive = false;
try {
    WebResponse^ resp = reqFTP->GetResponse();
    Encoding^ code;
    code = Encoding::GetEncoding(1251);
    reader = gcnew StreamReader(resp->GetResponseStream(), code);
    String^ line = reader->ReadToEnd();
    array<Char>^delimiters = gcnew array<Char>{
        '\r', '\n'
    };
    array<Char>^delimiters2 = gcnew array<Char>{
        ' '
    };
    array<String^>^words = line->Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions::RemoveEmptyEntries);
    array<String^>^DetPr;
    System::Collections::IEnumerator^ myEnum = words->GetEnumerator();
    while ( myEnum->MoveNext() ) {
        String^ word = safe_cast<String^>(myEnum->Current);
        DetPr = word->Split(delimiters2);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can't.  You are interpreting the raw result and there is no defined format for this data (or is there any requirement that this data be returned at all in the response).  And the FTP protocol does not define any other way of getting this.

What that leaves you with is a collection of parsing patterns for the server types you know about and working through them looking for valid data.  Not entirely easy.

Comment: does have the .net some 3d parties libraries for that?